# How to purposely test errors in a transaction?

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I have a stored procedure that has several transactions in a loop:

```
WHILE @COUNT < @MY_NUM
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  -- DO STUFF HERE

  IF(@@ERROR != 0)
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    BREAK
  END

  COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

I would now like to test whether or not my `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` and `BREAK` logic will work by purposely introducing an error to the loop after a certain number of runs and look at the data.

Furthermore, I run these stored procedures from a shell script. So, I would like to test by using `Ctrl + C` in the middle of a run. Will this work? If not, how can I purposely introduce an error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do one of the following:

1. Intentially cause an error like Divide by zero
2. Use [RaiseError()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can to use `print`:

```
WHILE @COUNT < @MY_NUM
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  print 'BEGIN TRANSACTION'
  -- DO STUFF HERE
  print '-- DO STUFF HERE'
  IF(@@ERROR != 0)
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    print 'ROLLBACK TRANSACTION @MY_NUM: %1!',convert(varchar,@MY_NUM)
    BREAK
  END

  COMMIT TRANSACTION
  print 'COMMIT TRANSACTION'
END
```

[Here](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/40446;pt=40544) it's link to documentation.